# Python: cv2 can't open USB camera. "error: (-215:Assertion failed)"

Tags: python, opencv

I'd like to use cv2 with a Desktop PC that I build myself. I've bought a USB webcamera and successufuly installed it since it works smoothly when I access it. My probem is that it seems that cv2 is not able to open my camera. This is the error I'm getting:

```
rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor
```

So I've tried using various index (from -1 to 5) in this line of code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

But nothing changed, I've also tried to use:

```
cd /dev

ls video
```

But this is the error I'm getting:

```
ls: cannot access 'video': No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: How do you access the camera successfully?  The path above shows that you are using WIndows.  `/dev/video` is a Linux concept.  Do you see the camera in Device Manager?  Remember that Windows uses exclusive access -- you cannot open the camera if another application is using it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Yes, I cann see my USB camera in the Device Manager and I'm sure the camera is not used by any other application. So I really don't know what the issue could be

Answer (score 0):

```
rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Before this line of code, did you also write something like cv2.imread(...)? I experienced the error exactly the same with yours when I mistakenly put a wrong image address in the cv2.imread(), so my advice is to double check if you pass a correct image address if there is any. Best:)

Comment: I'm not using ` cv2.imread()` anywhere and my code work just fine in my laptop. I've this problem only with my desktop PC that is using a USB Logitech camera